# SP2-0552: Bind variable "ELSE" not declared?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I don't understand why this error shows when I specified the conditions and treatement

```
sql>declare
    experience int;
    salaire employees.salary%type;
    begin
    select datediff(year,getdate(),hire_date),employees.salary into experience,salaire from employees where employee_id=115;
    dbms_output.put_line('Avant id=115 '||' experience='||experience||' salaire='||salaire);
    if experience>10 then salaire=salaire*1.2;
    elsif (experience>5 and experience <= 10) then salaire*1.1:
    else salaire=salaire*1.05;
    end if;
    dbms_output.put_line('Apres id=115 '||' experience='||experience||' salaire='||salaire);
    end;
```

Comment: `then salaire*1.1;`

Comment: This is not PL/SQL or Oracle code -- or at least it has a healthy does of SQL Server mixed in.  Are you sure you have tagged the correc database.

Comment: I see now that I have syntax errors

Answer (score 1):

When errors are fixed (`:=` instead of `=`, `;` instead of `:`, non-existent functions), then code looks like this:

```
DECLARE
   experience  INT;
   salaire     employees.salary%TYPE;
BEGIN
   SELECT EXTRACT (YEAR FROM SYSDATE) - EXTRACT (YEAR FROM e.hire_date),
          e.salary
     INTO experience, salaire
     FROM employees e
    WHERE e.employee_id = 115;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
         'Avant id=115 '
      || ' experience='
      || experience
      || ' salaire='
      || salaire);

   IF experience > 10
   THEN
      salaire := salaire * 1.2;
   ELSIF (    experience > 5
          AND experience <= 10)
   THEN
      salarie := salaire * 1.1;
   ELSE
      salaire := salaire * 1.05;
   END IF;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
         'Apres id=115 '
      || ' experience='
      || experience
      || ' salaire='
      || salaire);
END;
```

It depends on what `experience` is; I just subtracted `hire_date` year from current year.

Answer (score 0):

This line is not Oracle:

```
select datediff(year,getdate(),hire_date),employees.salary
into experience, salaire
from employees
where employee_id = 115;
```

I can speculate that you want something like this:

```
select floor( months_between( sysdate, hiredate ) / 12 ),
       employees.salary
into experience, salaire
from employees
where employee_id = 115;
```

This is not exactly the same logic that you have.  But it is probably a better definition of `experience` given what `datediff()` really does.

Comment: I'm working with sql command line and oracle database. is there another function that could calculate the years of experience . Could you please explain the difference btw using datediff and months_between

Comment: What, _exactly_, is "sql command line"? it sounds like it might be oracle's sqlplus.  Ultimately, it doesn't matter what your client program is. If you are working with oracle database, you have to use oracle sql and/or pl/sql.  You can't mix in syntax from other databases.